# How to get notified & access kurento media server recording?

Tags: kurento

I can successfully run the *one2one-call-advanced* java example. However I'm running the Kurento Media Server and the client (The example Java application) on different machines.

So I haven't figured out some things:

1. How can I get notified of a successful recording? When the WebRTC call ends, should I just assume that the recording is in the filesystem location specified by the parameters to *RecorderEndpoint.Builder*?
2. Does *Kurento* provide some mechanism to access the recording or should I use 3rd party tools (ftp access, scp, mounted Amazon S3 bucket) to make the recordings directory accessible to the network?
3. Are there any error conditions or messages that the *RecorderEndpoint* or *Pipeline* produce that I can use to determine the success/failure conditions or recording location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can expect that.
2. You can use a PlayerEndpoint, which is able of playing a video accessible to the KMS. You can indicate where the file is using a URI.
3. Not specifically, but all media elements have an *onError* event to which you can subscribe, and if any error occurs in the pipeline or in the endpoint, you'll get notified.

### Edit

The recorder now supports storing files directly in S3, without having to mount the volume in your server. This is available in the development branch of v6.2.0

Comment: per your Edit, did S3 storage make it to the stable release of Kurento?  I don't see any docs on it as of 6.6.0.  Thanks for pointing me to any docs on that.

Comment: Hi please guide us to the documentation.

Comment: At the moment using 6.16.0 kurento fails to put the file directly into s3 with `poll timed out after 0:00:30` and  `Error code 1: Internal data flow error`

Comment: I do not see either any fix related to writing the file in release 6.2.0 https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server/commits/6.2.0

Comment: It doesn't seem like it made it, but there's an alternative documente [here](https://groups.google.com/g/kurento/c/7Z8eKCGkEEg/m/2WpFjDn5DAAJ)